# Revert to an old commit in Bitbucket

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

I have git setup on my web hosting and on an account at Bitbucket which are both linked.

How can I revert back to my first commit on both my hosting (which I am logged into via SSH and has git installed ready and working) and on Bitbucket?

I have tried: `git checkout 965a793`

Then I tried with a dot on the end: `git checkout .`

but nothing seems to change on the Bitbucket side, when I got to git push. It says everything is up to date, even though Bitbucket is on commit `cf08232`

Here is a list of my three commits:

```
cf08232 remove the txt file
096d08f test.txt edited online with Bitbucket
965a793 Initial Commit
```

Answer (score 51):

Use --force :

```
 git reset --hard commitID
 git push origin branchName --force
```

I am assuming origin is the remote of bitbucket

Comment: Tried  "git reset --hard 965a793" then "git push origin master --force". Still Bitbucket appears unchanged. My contents of git branch -a are "master" and "remotes/origin/master"

Comment: @merch89 Reconfirm again. I check it in bitbucket  now, it works for me. When you do git log, does it show anything else apart from 965a793 commit. Before you do  git push origin master --force Confirm that

Comment: This post here seems to sort it **http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4114095/revert-git-repo-to-a-previous-commit?lq=1**     ```git reset 56e05fced, git reset --soft HEAD@{1}, git commit -m "Revert to 56e05fced" , git reset --hard```

Comment: @merch89 It won't be change in bitbucket. You need to use --force while pushing.

Comment: And --hard does that. I have verified it. Are you giving --hard  and then force?

Comment: The exact code posted above does the job both locally and bitbucket. Didn't use the --force command either. Thanks for your help.

Comment: If you are pushing something in bitbucket and it conflicts, bitbucket won't allow.

Comment: This is great, if I only knew that when Bitbucket rejects, only thing you need to do is force... :)

Answer (score 20):

Please note **git reset** is **dangerous**. I personally am not a fan because it deletes/modifies change history. If you want to rollback your changes to a specific commit without modifying the change history, I suggest using git revert instead:

```
git revert cf08232
git revert 096d08f
```

Each time you run git revert, it will create a new commit that undoes the changes introduced by a specific prior commit, without modifying the change history.

Here's a good [article](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/resetting-checking-out-and-reverting) that compares reset, checkout & revert.

Comment: Totally agree that reset and force push is not recommended, especially if many other people are working on the same repo.

Answer (score 1):

Use revert for rollback your past commit and push.

```
$git revert <commitId>
$git push
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).